# How can I disable backups for the Feed Me plugin in CraftCMS?

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

How can I disable backups for the `Feed Me` plugin in CraftCMS?

I already disabled general backups in `general.php` of Craft but now Feed Me is not happy with that saying that: `Database not backed up because the backup command is false. - Connection.php: 274`

How can I also disable backups before Feed Me runs? I could not find anything in Feed Mes official documentation. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable backups in the feed settings, there's a lightswitch field to control whether to backup before the feed is run. This is on the first page of editing a feed in Feed Me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just did not see that.